# Powershell to count and group Event ID 4625?

Tags: powershell

How can I get the total number of Event ID error 4625 and for each and every Windows Server in my AD domain using the below Powershell script?

```
$DCServers = Get-ADDomainController -filter * | select -ExpandProperty hostname

$events = @()
$totalCt = 0
$servers = @()

Foreach ($Server in $DCServers)
{
    Write-Host "Calling Get-WinEvent for $Server"
    $serverEvents = Get-WinEvent -ComputerName $Server -FilterHashtable @{ logname = 'Security'; id = 4625 } -EA 0
    if (!$?)
    {
        Write-Host "Get-WinEVent failure for $Server"
        continue
    }
    if ($null -ne $serverEvents)
    {
        $totalCt += $serverEvents.Count
        $servers += [PsCustomObject] @{ $server = $serverEvents.Count }
        Write-Host $server $serverEvents.Count
    }
    
    $serverEvents | ForEach-Object {
        $events += [PsCustomObject] @{
            Date = $_.TimeCreated
            "Event Id" = $_.Id
            "User Name" = $_.Properties[6].Value + "\" + $_.Properties[5].Value ## fixed
            "IPAddress" = $_.Properties[21].Value
            "FailureReason" = (($_.message -split "\n") | Select-String -Pattern "Failure Reason:\s+(.+)").matches[0].groups[1].value
            "Status Code" = $_.message -split '\s{4}' | Select-String -Pattern "Status"
            "Logon Type" = $_.Properties[10].Value
            "DC Logged On" = $_.Properties[13].value ## this is "workstation that processed the request", not the DC Logged On
        }
    }
    
}

$HTML = '<h1>Head</h1>'
$GetDate = Get-Date
$Report = 'C:\clu\temp-4625.html'

#convert the array of events to HTML
$Events |
Select-Object Date, "Event Id", "User Name", "FailureReason", "Status Code", "DC Logged On", "Logon Type" |
Convertto-html -head $HTML -PreContent "<H2>Accounts that Failed to Log On</H2>", "<H2>$GetDate </H2>" -PostContent "<p></p>Total 4625 records: $totalCt <p></p>" |
Out-File $Report -append

Write-Host "Total 4625 records: $totalCt"
Write-Host "4625 records per server:"
$servers | ft -auto

Write-Host "4625 records grouped by user"
$events | group "User Name" | sort Count
```

The goal is to see which servers have Event 4625 and group it by the content to see which IP or AD account failed logins where possible?

Comment: What's the question here? How to extract the workstation IP address from your events?

Answer (score 2):

Before digging into how to extract the workstation IP address and how to group the events by specific properties, let me suggest rewriting your existing code slightly, given your goal.

Doing `$event = New-Object psobject |Select listOfPropertyNames` and then assigning the values to each property separately is going to be *slow* - something I imagine you might want to avoid if you have many servers to query.

Since PowerShell 3.0, we can instantiate a new custom object in one go with the following syntax:

```bsh
$newObject = [pscustomobject]@{
    PropertyName = "Value"
}
```

So, refactoring your existing code, we end up with something like:

```bsh
$events += [pscustomobject]@{
    Date            = $_.TimeCreated
    "Event Id"      = $_.Id
    "User Name"     = $_.Properties[5].Value + "\" + $_.Properties[6].Value
    "FailureReason" = (($_.Message -split "\n") | Select-String -Pattern "Failure Reason:\s+(.+)").Matches[0].Groups[1].Value
    "Status Code"   = $_.Message -split '\s{4}' | Select-String -Pattern "Status"
    "Logon Type"    = $_logontype[ [int] $_.Properties[10].Value ]
    "DC Logged On"  = $_.Properties[13].Value
}
```

Another change we might wanna make is change the data type of `$events` - when you instantiate an empty array with `@()`, PowerShell will allow you to add new items to the array with `+=`, but there's a catch - arrays are of a fixed size, so if you keep adding new items via `+=`, PowerShell will have to stop and *resize* the array by creating a larger underlying array and then copying the existing array items into the new, larger array. This obviously takes some *time* and might incur unnecessary memory acquisition as well.

To work around this, use a list instead - lists are designed with dynamic sizing in mind, so will perform better even when you add a 1000s of items to it:

```bsh
$events = New-Object 'System.Collections.Generic.List[psobject]'
```

---

Now, back to the question - how to group all the events by IP address - first of all, we need to *extract* the workstation IP address in order to me able to group on it later, so let's add an extra property to the custom object we created:

```bsh
$events += [pscustomobject]@{
    # ... 
    IPAddress  = $_.Properties[21].Value
}
```

Now that the IPAddress is present, grouping the objects based on it is as simple as:

```bsh
$events | Group-Object IPAddress
```

Comment: thank you for the suggestion, however, I got the error:
Cannot index into a null array.
At line:20 char:20
+ ... tus Code" = $_.Message -split '\s{4}' | Select-String -Pattern "Statu ...
+              
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray

Comment: I have updated the code as above.
Would it be possible to send it as HTML email result?

Comment: @SeniorSystemsEngineer That seems to be an issue with how you attempt to extract the failure reason - code from your _orignal question_ - to solve it I'd suggest looking at the [approach suggested in js2010's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63418287/712649). In any case, it would be easier to help you if you _actually described the problems/errors/issues you're having_ instead of just stating "This is the end goal"

Answer (score 2):

Note that you can also get these fields from the xml of the event:

```
$a = Get-WinEvent -Max 1 @{logname='Security'; id=4625}
$xml = [xml]$a.ToXml()
$xml.event.EventData.data

Name                      #text
----                      -----
SubjectUserSid            S-1-5-18
SubjectUserName           COMP$
SubjectDomainName         DOM
SubjectLogonId            0x3e7
TargetUserSid             S-1-0-0
TargetUserName            admin
TargetDomainName          COMP
Status                    0xc000006d
FailureReason             %%2313
SubStatus                 0xc000006a
LogonType                 7
LogonProcessName          User32
AuthenticationPackageName Negotiate
WorkstationName           COMP
TransmittedServices       -
LmPackageName             -
KeyLength                 0
ProcessId                 0xa60
ProcessName               C:\Windows\System32\svchost.exe
IpAddress                 127.0.0.1
IpPort                    0
```

Compare with .Properties

```
$a.properties

Value
-----
S-1-5-18
COMP$
DOM
999
S-1-0-0
admin
COMP
-1073741715
%%2313
-1073741718
7
User32
Negotiate
COMP
-
-
0
2656
C:\Windows\System32\svchost.exe
127.0.0.1
0
```